# How to make right sql query with my situation

Tags: java, android, mysql, sql

Idea is here, but it is not working, hot to make it right, I am a totally begginer)

```
String temperature = editText5.getText().toString();
String percent = editText7.getText().toString();

Cursor c1 = db.query("mytable", null, "temperature, percent = ?", new String[]{temperature, percent}, null, null, null);

if (c1.moveToFirst()) {
    int ckoef = c1.getColumnIndex("ckoef");
    int density = c1.getColumnIndex("density");

    do {
        textView9.setText(c1.getString(ckoef));
        textView11.setText(c1.getString(density));
    } while (c1.moveToNext());

} else

c1.close();
```

The table looks like this

```
ID = 1, temperature = 0, percent = 10, ckoef = 4.025, density = 1012.5
ID = 2, temperature = 10, percent = 10, ckoef = 4.034, density = 1012.5
ID = 3, temperature = 20, percent = 10, ckoef = 4.043, density = 1012.5
ID = 4, temperature = 30, percent = 10, ckoef = 4.057, density = 1012.5
ID = 5, temperature = 40, percent = 10, ckoef = 4.075, density = 1012.5
ID = 6, temperature = 50, percent = 10, ckoef = 4.085, density = 1012.5
ID = 7, temperature = 60, percent = 10, ckoef = 4.094, density = 1012.5
ID = 8, temperature = 70, percent = 10, ckoef = 4.103, density = 1012.5
ID = 9, temperature = 80, percent = 10, ckoef = 4.113, density = 1012.5
ID = 10, temperature = 90, percent = 10, ckoef = 4.122, density = 1012.5
ID = 11, temperature = 100, percent = 10, ckoef = 4.132, density = 1012.5
```

etc for percent 10 - 50 with a step 10

So please help.

Comment: How is it not working? What is it doing, and what do you want it to do?

Comment: Try `"temperature = ? AND percent = ?"` instead of `"temperature, percent = ?"`

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-20 03:40:36.958 20254-20254/com.example.prog E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.prog, PID: 20254
E/AndroidRuntime: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ",": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE temperature, percent = ?

Comment: Titus, thanks, it is work!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Cursor c1 = db.query("mytable", null, "temperature = ? and percent = ?", temperature , percent , null, null, null);

Answer (score 0):

For querying the sqlite database using cursor

```
Cursor c1 = db.query("mytable", null, "temperature=? and percent=?", new String[] { temperature, percent }, null, null, null);
```

where the `new string[]` represents the values for temperature and percent values respectively